# How to transform a slice of dataframe into a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I'm new to python and I'm confused sometimes with some operations
I have a dataframe called `ro` and I also have filtered this dataframe using a specific column `PN 3D` for a specific value `921` and I assigned the results into a new data frame called `headlamp` by using the following code:

```
 headlamp = ro[ro['PN 3D']=="921"]
```

Does my headlamp is also a **dataframe** or is just a **slice**?
The reason I'm asking this is because I'm getting some strange warnings and results later on my script.

Such as, I create a new column called `word` and I assigned to `headlamp`

```
 headlamp['word'] = ""
```

I got the following warning:

```
 A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

After that I used the following script to assign the results to `headlamp['word']`

```
 i = 0
 for row in headlamp['Comment'].astype(list):
     headlamp['word'][i] = Counter(str(row).split())
 i+=1
 print headlamp['word']
```

The same warning appeared and it has impacted on my results, because when I used the `headlamp.tail()`, The last rows of `headlamp['word']` were empty.

Does anyone has an idea what is the problem and how to fix?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: `headlamp = ro[ro['PN 3D']=="921"].copy()`

Comment: if `headlamp` is a dataframe, the you should assign a `series` object to a column, not just an empty string. Something like `headlamp['word'] = pd.Series(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your both reply. I have used this `.copy()` and I have the same warnings and erros @MaxU. Regarding your reply @TammoHeeren, I also have assigned 0 values to all rows into column `word`, however after I applied the script, 

`i = 0 
for row in headlamp['Comment']:
    headlamp['word'][i] = (Counter(str(row).split()))
    i+=1
print headlamp['word']i = 0
for row in headlamp['Comment']:
    headlamp['word'][i] = (Counter(str(row).split()))
    i+=1
print headlamp['word']`

Comment: I got the same problem that I descrived above, the script is not applied to all rows from my dataframe `headlamp`. Do you guys now why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc`

```
headlamp = ro.loc[ro['PN 3D']=="921"]
```

---

As for the rest and your comments... I'm very confused.  But this is my best guess

***setup***

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase

chars = ascii_lowercase + ' '
probs = [0.03] * 26 + [.22]

headlamp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(chars), (10, 100), p=probs)).sum(1).to_frame('comment')
headlamp
```

[image]

```
headlamp['word'] = headlamp.comment.str.split().apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).to_dict())
headlamp
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared, it seems with `.loc` has worked with the warnings, but I still facing one problem and if you can help I will appreciate.

'i = 0
for row in headlamp['Comment']:
    headlamp.loc[i,'word'] = (Counter(str(row).split()))
    i+=1
print headlamp['word']` and I had the following error: `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Do you have any idea where might be the problem?

Comment: let me write again the script

`i = 0 for row in headlamp['Comment']: headlamp.loc[i,'word'] = (Counter(str(row).split())) i+=1`

Comment: I'm trying to create a dictionary on the column `word` by calculating the occurences of each words on the column `Comment` for each row of my dataframe

Comment: @RafaelRodriguesSantos I tried to figure out what you meant.  hopefully my edit is helpful

Comment: amazingly done, thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

To convert a slice into new dataframe, do this **slice.copy()**

Comment: Can you be more thorough with your answer?